# Is $\text{Log}({1\over z})=-\text{Log} ({1\over z})$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Is $\text{Log}({1\over z})=-\text{Log} ({1\over z})$ ? (This is exactly what the sub-question stated, following "Is $\log({1\over z})=-\log(z)$". Do you believe a typo could be involved?)

A question I did solve before, showed that $\log ({1\over z})=-\ln|z|+i{\text{Arg}({\overline{z}\over |z|^2}})+2\pi i k=-\ln|z|+i{\text{Arg}({\overline{z} }})+2\pi i k=-\ln|z|+i{\text{Arg}(e^{i(2\pi-\text{Arg(z)})})}+2\pi i k=-(\ln|z|+i\text{Arg}(z)+2\pi i m)=-\log(z)$,

but here I am confused. I know that $\text{Log}$ is the principle branch, but I am not quite sure hot to express it here, and why it is important: it seems as though it isn't correct but how does one show it? It seems like a complex question pretending to be direct. Do you have any insights about that, and, following my insecurity, any remarks about what I showed above?

Comment: In your title and first line, it seems you wanted "$\operatorname{Log} \left(\frac{1}{z}\right) = - \operatorname{Log} (z)$".

Comment: And for the principal branch of the logarithm, that is true.

Comment: I did show $\log ({1\over z})=-\log (z)$, (although wasn't required to show that about $\text{Log}$.). However, this is exactly what the question presented. Do you assume it was consistently meant to be $-\text{Log}(z)$ in an attempt to make the students understnad the difference between the branches?

Comment: @DanielFischer: Except on the negative real axis, where $-\operatorname{Log}(z)$ is out of the range of $\operatorname{Log}$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm that's not part of the domain of the principal branch in the definition I learned.

Comment: But what do you think I should do? Simply show the statement above is not generally correct, or take the possibility that it was meant to be asked whether $\text{Log}({1\over z})=-\text{Log}(z)$ into account?

Comment: It was probably a typo. For every branch of the logarithm on a domain $U \subset \mathbb{C}$ with $U = U^{-1} = \{z^{-1} : z\in U\}$, one has $\log z + \log (z^{-1}) \equiv 2\pi i k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, but for most branches, $k \neq 0$. One has $k = 0$ for the principal branch $\operatorname{Log} \colon \mathbb{C}\setminus (-\infty,0] \to \mathbb{C}$, since $\operatorname{Log} 1 + \operatorname{Log} 1^{-1} = 0 + 0 = 0$.

Comment: What do I do, then? I did I show that $\text{Arg}(\overline{z})=-\text{Arg}({z})$. I tried $\text{Arg}{e^{i\theta_{\overline{z}}}}$ where $-\pi<\theta_{\overline{z}}\le \pi$, but I don't know how to procceed in a way that I can explain by real understnading. I really need to avoid using adjectives like "real" and "complex" in that section..

Comment: @DanielFischer: The definition I learned defines the "principal argument" on the entire punctured plane with range $(-\pi,\pi]$ and uses that to build a $\operatorname{Log}$ function with the same domain in the obvious way. But it stands to reason that different authors will make different choices here.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yes, indeed. I learned that a branch of the logarithm on $U$ is a holomorphic $f \colon U \to \mathbb{C}$ such that $\exp(f(z)) \equiv z$ on $U$. That requires the domain of a branch of the logarithm to be open. The principal branch is the branch on $\mathbb{C}\setminus (-\infty,0]$ taking the value $0$ at $1$.